# WinKey + R not always working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

When I press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the run-command, it started not working all the time. I don't recall if it's been there since I've installed Windows 10 or appeared after, but I would like it if I didn't have to install it all over again.

I don't use a wireless keyboard.

Tests I've done:

- <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>,
  <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>) works fine
  all the time, as does the <kbd>WinKey</kbd> itself to open the Start Menu.
- When I'm in Chrome browser (for example) and I scroll a page, it's
  enough for <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to be ignored. I have to
  change focus to another window (e.g., to Command Prompt) and only then
  can I press (<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) twice to open the
  Run dialog. (But it's not consistent when I have to do this – it might
  work first try!)
- <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, for example, doesn't yield any result.
- If I click the taskbar (the one that used to contain the 'Start' button) and press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, it works!

I was thinking that it could be due to some program catching the key-combination, but I can't seem to find any (did scans with S&D, AVG, Ad-Aware).

Any ideas what it might be or how I can debug this?

Comment: `WinKey + R` has not changed.  If it isn't working for you then something is unique about your system.  Use AutoRuns to disable pretty much everything that automatically loads when you log into your profile to determine if its software that is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

> I encountered the same problem, that all other shortcuts with <kbd>WinKey</kbd> seemed to work perfectly fine, except for <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
>
> ### Symptoms
>
> <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> sometimes (rarely) worked on the the first try, sometimes after the 2nd or 3rd try, and sometimes it did not work at all; except when first focusing the Windows taskbar.
>
> ### Cause
>
> This occurred immediately after installing Windows 10 (more precisely upgrading from Windows 7 to 10).
>   So, installing Windows 10 was most probably the cause (on my system) for this is.
>
> ### <s>Solution</s>
>
> <s>For me, uninstalling `Adobe Flash` did solve this problem</s>

*[EDIT] my "solution" seems to have been a fluke: it seemed to work for a about a week, then it reverted to the old problem ... so I still have no idea what causes this problem*

**[EDIT 2] this problem is solved / does not occur anymore since updating to Windows 10 `ver. 1607`**

Comment: This is very, very peculiar.

Comment: as it turns out, it was not really a solution:

Comment: ... when the problem seemed to be resolved, I tested it multiple times, re-booted, again tested it multiple times, and it really seemed to be resolved; the thing that I did immediately before the problem disappeared was uninstalling Flash ... but a few days later, the problem appeared again, so uninstalling Flash was obviously not the solution to the problem...  (I edited my initial answer above to reflect this turn of events)

Comment: At the time when Win+R is not reacting, is Win+X still working?

Comment: yes -- as far as I can make out, all other WinKey shortcuts do work, except for Win+R

Answer (score 0):

(I speak broken English..)
My symptom is the same as russa above. This is definitely caused by the hot key occupation. I suggest you can cancel something in msconfig and reboot, and when you find you can use win+r smoothly, check for the hotkey of the software you cancel. Or you can find the target software when you close this software, or the software works incorrectly.
For me, I have found that **when my WOX is working, I can't use win+R**. And when I press win+R, my Wox will become a short bar, I can only restart Wox to let it recover.
[wox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QddOP.png)

So I untick this above, and solve the problem successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have a portable application called Capture2Text which has OCR capabilities to grab text from videos and images. This program uses the Win key for quite a lot of its default hotkeys, so while the program is open the conflicting Windows key combinations will not work. Changing all the default hotkeys in its settings by adding modifiers such as Alt/Shift resolves the conflicts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).